# How to force flushing in Grails GORM

Tags: grails, transactions, flush

I have a service that distributes tasks to operators.
Inside a method I distribute many tasks in time inside a loop. I want to flush the task, the operator, and a DistributionLog. If I just had one domain to save I think I could do something like

```
Operator.withTransaction{ //...some code }
```

but I have at least 3 domains to save and to make it even worse, two of them have dependency on each other. The operator have a list of tasks.

I can't wait all the distribution to finish before an operator can get his tasks, so I have to force it to flush. To make it even harder, it's all inside a multitenantService.doWithTenant() (multitenant plugin)

Comment: I'm sorry Ithink I should have informed that I have already tried to call flush on the last .save() call, but it didn't work. I don't know if it is because all is happening inside the doWithTenant but what I know is that it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the session using the `withSession` method available in all domain classes and call to `flush()` on it.

```
Operator.withSession { session ->
   // ...
   session.flush()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do an explicit flush, you can get a reference to the hibernate session factory in your grails service like this:

```
def sessionFactory
```

You can then get the current hibernate session, and call flush on that:

```
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force a flush with `flush` argument to the last call to `save`:

```
obj.save flush:true
```

Comment: The Object is not flushed right away. Only when the Transaction is commited, or the session is flushed, the Object is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

```
The save method informs the persistence context that an instance should be saved or updated. The object will not be persisted immediately unless the flush argument is used:

b.save(flush: true)
```