# Flush session in controller, after I saved

Tags: session, grails, flush, grails-controller

I have a problem about how to flush away my session after I have used it. I have called out a session and when it safe it, I want it to be flushed away.

*On the save() controller it has `.save flush:true` but why the session had not be flushed away?*

I have done some research about flushing session but unfortunately I am too noob to understand it.

**Related Post :**

1. [How to force flushing in Grails GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486949/how-to-force-flushing-in-grails-gorm)
2. [Do I ever need to explicitly flush GORM save calls in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288991/do-i-ever-need-to-explicitly-flush-gorm-save-calls-in-grails)

Controller :

```css
def create(){


   def project = session['projectName'] // call out my session
   def projectNames     = Project.findAllByProjectName(project.projectName) // find out the project name inside my session and assign it in to "projectNames"
   
   model:[projectNames:projectNames] // pass it to GSP and to let the user choose from the drop down
 
   projectNames.save flush:true // but is an error
   projectNames.currentSession.flush() //got no class currentSession

}
```

**EDIT 1**

```css
def save() //generated by grails
{

project.save flush:true
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards, Hee

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should look is the below line

```
def projectNames = Project.findAllByProjectName(project.projectName)
```

You are fetching the list of projects matching with the name  `project.projectName`, so it returns an list of Project instance `List<Project> projectNames`.

You should call the

```
projectNames*.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

I dont see any update operation in your code so just wndering why do you really need an save opration here.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! "Create" controller is a form, it's generate by grails. (generate-all), so my "Safe" controller will be the button "create" that generate by grails.
Since "safe" has the code "flush:true" why issit the session not flushed? 
* I have updated my save() controller